# Webscarab refusing connections with all browsers

Tags: java, linux, browser, proxy, penetration-testing

Hi I am using webscarab as proxy to see the conversations between my browser and server. I havent used webscarab in a while. It was ok when I used it before. But now all the connections are refused , with all browsers or ports. It is showing an exception like below.

```
WebScarab encountered an error trying to retrieve

GET http://www.gooogle.com:80/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.gooogle.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

The error was :

Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.httpclient.URLFetcher.connect(URLFetcher.java:368)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.httpclient.URLFetcher.fetchResponse(URLFetcher.java:229)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.CookieTracker$Plugin.fetchResponse(CookieTracker.java:130)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.BrowserCache$Plugin.fetchResponse(BrowserCache.java:101)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.RevealHidden$Plugin.fetchResponse(RevealHidden.java:100)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.BeanShell$Plugin.fetchResponse(BeanShell.java:229)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.ManualEdit$Plugin.fetchResponse(ManualEdit.java:243)
    at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.ConnectionHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:233)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

This is the error I get from firefox now. I tried changing the listener ports, and browsers. But no use. Still getting same exception. Can someone please help.

Comment: Sounds like you have an upstream proxy configured, pointing to an unreachable address. Either that, or you simply cannot reach google from where you are. (Unlikely, I admit)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that there is a proxy configured in WebScarab itself, that WebScarab cannot reach. To check this, go to Tools -> Proxies, and make sure that there is no proxy configured (unless you need an upstream proxy to reach the sites normally, in which case make sure that that is properly configured.)

[Connection between javafx2.2 webengine and webscarab fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294436/connection-between-javafx2-2-webengine-and-webscarab-fails)

it worked for me.